# GLB/GLTF model will not display correctly in Google AR but shows no errors in other viewers

Tags: three.js, arcore

I'm using three.js to generate a 3D model and export it as GLB or GLTF using THREE.GLTFExporter.  Goal is to make it viewable on our site using google AR.

https://kaboomlaser.com/pages/ar-test  (link to files)

The model looks perfectly fine when I view it in https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/  or other GLTF/glb viewers.

See here: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/#model=https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0290/5459/9273/files/test.glb

but when I open it in Googles AR scene previewer  https://vr.google.com/scene-viewer-preview , it ends up empty.
Other models I tried did show up in scene previewer, but with the meshes all spiky and weird.

Below the code I used to reproduce the issue with a simple model.  (This outputs the models in the link above).

What am I missing?

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
    var heartShape = new THREE.Shape();
    heartShape.moveTo(x + 5, y + 5);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 5, y + 5, x + 4, y, x, y);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x - 6, y, x - 6, y + 7, x - 6, y + 7);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x - 6, y + 11, x - 3, y + 15.4, x + 5, y + 19);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 12, y + 15.4, x + 16, y + 11, x + 16, y + 7);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 16, y + 7, x + 16, y, x + 10, y);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 7, y, x + 5, y + 5, x + 5, y + 5);

    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(heartShape, {
        depth: 4, bevelEnabled: false,
        bevelThickness: 0.4,
        bevelSize: 0.4,
        steps: 2,
        BevelSegments: 2,
        curveSegments: 10
    });

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xa00A0A });
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(mesh);

    const options = {
        binary: true,
        forceIndices: true
    };

    var exporter = new GLTFExporter();

    exporter.parse(scene, function (data) {
        if (options.binary) {
            savetoFile(data, 'test.glb', 'model/gltf-binary');
        }
        else {
            savetoFile(JSON.stringify(data), 'test.gltf', 'text/plain');
        }
    },
    options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with some of the models I got from Poly.
Try to Import the model in Blender and Export again. I tried with your model and it works fine